# How do I whitelist my Google account to prevent it ever triggering captcha?

Tags: selenium, recaptcha, google-oauth

We have a number of Google Sheets accounts specifically dedicated for use by test automation. Our tests use Selenium to automate the Google auth flow and then the rest of the test flow.

Starting Friday (6 Oct 2017) we are seeing Google sometimes inserts captchas into the auth flow. We don't see any consistency in which tests, or which test machines, get captchas and which don't. In some runs we see almost every test encounter captchas, in other runs we see only a few get captchas. We never see captchas when manually executing the test scenarios, and manually solving the captchas as the tests run does not prevent future captchas.

We've seen this sporadically in the past, and it has always gone away on its own. This time it appears to be sticking around.

Given the whole point of these test accounts are to be used by bots, and the whole point of captcha is to prove the user is not a bot, we looked through the settings for the Google accounts for something along the lines of "Never captcha this account" and didn't see any likely candidates. Our searches of StackOverflow and the web for variants of "[google-oauth] [recaptcha] whitelisting" and the like haven't turned up anything beyond "The whole point of captcha is to not be automatable, duh", which we already knew and doesn't help us get our tests running.

Is there a way to whitelist these accounts to never trigger captcha?

Comment: Is there some reason you don't convert these to Excel sheets (or CSV or other data format) so that you can include them with the tests? It would avoid the whole Captcha issue and speed up your tests since you don't have to hit the internet, etc.

Comment: I'm not sure this is even a programming question... sounds like a support question to google.

Comment: @JeffC It's the connection to/communication between our app and Google Sheets that we're testing, not the data itself.

Google's OAuth support forums say to post to Stack Exchange, and this seemed the most relevant site. I'll happily post elsewhere if you think a different Stack Exchange site is more appropriate. We are following up with Google's account support as well.

Comment: Posted Google's official answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's Google's [official answer](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/67954589):

> "There isn't. If you're using a gsuite domain for your test accounts, however, you can run your own identity provider to handle the auth. Not entirely sure if that avoids it 100% of the time though."